# question about information_schema.TABLES result

Tags: mysql, percona

1.we use this sql check big object info of mysql,

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,
       TABLE_NAME,
       CONCAT(ROUND(DATA_LENGTH/1024/1024),'MB') AS DATA_LENGTH,
       CONCAT(ROUND(INDEX_LENGTH/1024/1024),'MB') AS INDEX_LENGTH,
       CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(DATA_LENGTH+INDEX_LENGTH)/1024/1024),'MB') AS TOTDB_SIZE,
       TABLE_ROWS
FROM information_schema.TABLES  
where TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('information_schema','performance_schema','sys')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME 
order by 6 desc limit 50
```

the sql result is:

```
TABLE_SCHEMA TABLE_NAME      DATA_LENGTH  INDEX_LENGTH TOTDB_SIZE    TABLE_ROWS
report       report_opr_detl 1078MB         0MB             1078MB      1778206
```

it report table report_opr_detl size is 1078MB .the number rows is 1778206 ,

2.but when we check the table size in os filesystem.

> it report the size is 1.5G. it is diffrent wih step 1 result (1078MB)

```
[root@pommodb02 report]# du -sh report_opr_detl*

46K     report_opr_detl.frm
1.5G    report_opr_detl.ibd
```

> it report the count(*) of the table is 2162772 rows. it is diffrent wih step 1 result (1778206 rows)

```
 mysql> select count(*) from report.report_opr_detl;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2162772 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.65 sec)
```

3.so my question is why step 1 and step 2 is different ,

Comment: There's no need for `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`. There's only one row per table, so there's nothing to group.

Comment: Is this an InnoDB table? Table size information is only approximate.

Comment: yes, it is an innodb table, ok ,see it is only approximate

Comment: @Barmar, table_rows and avg_row_size are estimated based on sampling a few pages, but the data_length, index_length, and data_free are based on the number of physical extents allocated for the tablespace, so it should be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

- The `SUM` did not include `Data_free`.
- `TABLE_ROWS` is an approximation for InnoDB; the `COUNT(*)` is exact.
- Another way to get similar info is `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.